# missing items before go live

Tags: java

Before my java application go live, I decided to do/re check followings

```
1)  Code reviews
2)  Run tools (PMD , Findbug , Checkstyle)
3)  Proper Exception Handling in place
4)  correct/meaning full  logs are in place.
5)  Unit tests.
```

Are there any missing items That I need to follow up when considering the java source I have developed.

Comment: What kind of application? Do you need to test it with real data? How about testing it in a Production like QA environment? And performance testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few more you can consider

1. Integration test (though you have already mentioned unit test)
2. Load test
3. Can do functional test of the application by deploying in one of the box/server which is replica of the production.